# Can test accuracy be greater than validation accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am working on facial expression recognition using FER-2013 dataset and getting validation accuracy as 67.317% and test accuracy as 68.960%. Is this correct to get such result?

Comment: You are getting it, so why it would not be correct? There are no constraints on test/validation metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, it is possible to have a higher test accuracy than the validation accuracy.
Let's imagine we have the following data points:

```
    X   Y
1   0   1
2   1   2
3   2   1
4   3   2
5   4   0
6   5   2
```

And we want to build a linear regression (the same is true for classification problems like facial recognition). Let's assume we take point 1-4 for training, point 5 for validation and point 6 for testing. This is just a simplified example.
By taking the points 1-4 for training, our regression equation would be:

```
ŷ = 0.2X + 1.2
```

Now, let's calculate the MSE (for accuracy for classification problem it would be equivalent).
Validation Error: `(0.2*4+1.2 -0)^2 = 7.84`
Test Error: `(0.2*5+1.2-2)^2 = 1.44`
As you can see, the validation error is higher than the test error.

---

But this sample is just theoretically. In generell, the test error is higher than validation error. ***Why?***
**You use the validation set to tune your hyperparameters**. Therefore, the validation error will decrease by tuning the hyperparameters and get lower than your test error, because you don't tune your hyperparamaters for the test set.
Therefore, if the accuracy of your validation set is lower than your test set, maybe you haven't tuned the hyperparameters of your model correctly.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to proceed for checking the tuning of hyperparameters of my model. Thank you for the help.